# What Service Needs to be on to translate UserSID

Tags: powershell, wmi, sid

I have a script which accepts following input

"sender-ip=10.10.10.10"

It is supposed to return the last user logged on.

First, it will attempt to detect Operating System

Second, it will attempt to detect User Profile

Finally, it will attempt to translate Security Identifier into a user account, i.e. DOMAIN\username

Here is relevant part of code

```
$Sender_IP = $my_hash.Get_Item("sender-ip")

try
{
    <#Gather information on the computer corresponding to $Sender_IP#>
    $Win32OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Sender_IP -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotDetectOS "
    return $output = "userId=" + $userId
}

try
{
    $Win32User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $Sender_IP -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotDetectUserProfile "
    return $output+= "userId=" + $userId
}

$Win32User = $Win32User | Sort-Object -Property LastUseTime -Descending
$LastUser = $Win32User | Select-Object -First 1


try
{
    $UserSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($LastUser.SID)
    $userId = $UserSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotDetectUserSID "
    return $output = "userId=" + $userId 
}

$userId = $userId.Value

if ($userId -ne $NULL){
    $output = "userId=" + $userId
}
elseif ($userID -eq $NULL)
{
    $userId = "Unknown/UserID"
    $output = "userId=" + $userId
}


$output.replace("\","/")
```

From what I understand, WMI service needs to be turned on in order to detect Windows Operating system, i.e.

```
$Win32OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Sender_IP -ErrorAction Stop
```

and Windows User Profile, i.e.

```
$Win32User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $Sender_IP -ErrorAction Stop
```

But what service needs to be turned on to properly translate Security Identifier, i.e.

```
$Win32User = $Win32User | Sort-Object -Property LastUseTime -Descending
$LastUser = $Win32User | Select-Object -First 1


try
{
    $UserSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($LastUser.SID)
    $userId = $UserSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotDetectUserSID "
    return $output = "userId=" + $userId 
}
```

One week I will run the script with "sender-ip=10.10.10.10" and get the actual user, and the next week script throws "CannotDetectUserProfile", and next week script throws "CannotDetectOS", etc

What service needs to be turned on, and can I do this remotely through powershell?

Comment: Your exception handling is dropping the actual error information. Add a line `$UserID, $_ >> 'C:\path\to\error.log'` and take a look at the error message in the log file.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers ok I am trying this